# Find the indices of Unique?

Tags: r

maybe this is too simple but I didn't find a good answer for this question. How can I find the indices of unique rows in a vector? I'm looking for the first occurences. For example :

```
a=c(1,2,4)
b=c(1,2,4)
c=c(1,3,9)
abc=rbind(a,b,c)
```

so the vector looks like:

```
a    1    2    4
b    1    2    4
c    1    3    9
```

Now I need the indices for the unique rows, how can I do this?

```
1 3
```

Comment: `which(!duplicated(abc))`

Comment: `which(!duplicated(abc))` the `duplicated` function is documented the same place as `unique`

Comment: @A. Webb thanks for your response. How should I find the last occurrence? For instance in my example above: output of 2 3 instead of 1 3. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- unique(abc)
rownames(x)
```

should return the unique row names "a" and "c"
if you want the indices as number:

```
rownames(abc) <- 1:nrow(abc)
x <- unique(abc)
indices <- as.numeric(rownames(x))
```